# Another structure

Tags: synonyms

What can I say instead  “I’ve heard a lot about Shanghai”?

I want to say it in another structure because I don’t want to use a lot repeatedly. Can I use ‘ a great deal’? But the sentence seems unusual and strange?

Comment: What makes the difference between a correct answer and an incorrect answer? Did you already look up "much" in a thesaurus, what did it say, and how are you unclear about the words you found?

Comment: You could say: "I’ve heard a great deal about Shanghai".

Answer (score 1):

'Much' & 'many' are used in negative and interrogative sentences.
They are used in affirmative sentences but in this case much or many begin the sentence.
'A  lot of’ can be used in all sentences : affirmative, negative and interrogative.

“I’ve heard a lot about Shanghai." ✔

“I’ve heard much about Shanghai." ✖

“I haven't heard much about Shanghai." ✔

Comment: thanks. Is there any other way that I can say the same meaning because I repeated a lot of “a lot” in my paragraph?